# GET a Salesforce Batch request using workbench

Tags: rest, web-services, salesforce, apex, workbench

I am using the following [syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_batches_get_request.htm) to get a batch request for bulk data load job from performed in our dev org

`https://instance_name—api.salesforce.com/services/async/APIversion/job/jobid/batch/batchId/request`

In workbench I went to REST Explorer clicked GET and used the following query:

`/services/async/v29.0/job/7501j000000Lb31/batch/7501g000000l0Lf`

When clicking on execute, I get the following error message:

`{"exceptionCode":"InvalidSessionId","exceptionMessage":"Unable to find session id"}`

My end goal is to be able to pull all view request csvs from a bulk data load job instead of having to download each one of them manually

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, you might be logged out. Try again by logging in?

Comment: even when doing it from the developer console it does not work, for some reason as soon as I get connected to workbench I get disconnected from the org